# Is it necessary to use "in" twice here?

Tags: prepositions

In the sentence

> In this lecture and in the ones to come...

is the second "in" necessary? Or is the sentence

> In this lecture and the ones to come...

correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## No,

it's not necessary. There's [nothing different enough in the two objects to require a different or repeated preposition](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/parallel-structure-prepositions/). The only effective difference is a minor issue of pacing and focus, taking the two objects as a group together or separately.